# Can i have a model that belongs_to another model under two different names in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

That is, I have Attachment model that belongs_to User model, User has_many attachments. I want the User as well to have many Attachments under another name, Extras lets say.
So when I call User.attachments will bring me a group, but calling User.extras will bring another, of the same class.
I am sure there is a problem with my approach as I can not find anything similar in the guides.

```
#User model
class User < ApplicationRecord
 
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :extras, class_name: "Attachment", dependent: :destroy #my guess

end

#Attachment model
Class Attachment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :user, as: "Extra", optional: true #my guess

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to distinguish 2 kinds of attachment, your `Attachment` model must have something for clarifying. Suppose you have a column named `kind` to do so:

```rb
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  enum kind: {
    attachment: 1,
    extra: 2
  }
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

By having this setup, you can make two `has_many` relations at `User` model using conditions for them:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, -> { where kind: Attachment.kinds[:attachment] }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :extras, class_name: "Attachment", -> { where kind: Attachment.kinds[:extra] }, dependent: :destroy
end
```

P/S: You can use STI to distinguish between 2 kinds of attachment as well

Comment: a little more concise would be to use enumerable scope, `has_many :attachments, ->{ merge(Attachment.attachment)}`

Comment: Thank you, this is so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You need a condition to distinguish attachments from extras, for example:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, -> { where(extra: false) }
  has_many :extras, -> {where(extra: true) }, class_name: "Attachment"
end

class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

NB the second belongs_to in the Attachment class is not required.

Comment: Thank you, I love this compact elegant solution.